# Google Colaboratory and Google Drive integration fails

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am not able to save a new notebook in my Google Drive environment.

Google Colaboratory works with predefined notebooks such as Hello, Colaboratory, but I am not able to save any into my Drive folder.
I have the Colaboratory app allowed in the Google Drive settings and really dont know how to solve it. Colaboratory communicates with Drive - it even creates the notebook files in the Google Drives folder, but when loading any notebook file it always report following Notebook loading error

> There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.

Neither the details of the error help much:

> Failed to fetch TypeError: Failed to fetch

I was playing with the access rights of both the file and the folder and could not find any solution.

**Update**: Chrome  64.0.3282.167 (64 bit); Windows 10 1709. I use two users on the Chrome. Creating Notebooks works normally on different computers with my username.
This is the output from console:
[Chrome Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBPHE.png)

Comment: Have you tried getting an [authorization token](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth) when requesting access to drive api?

Comment: What browser, browser version, and OS are you using?

Do you see any errors in the JS console?

Are you using multilogin (multiple users logged into the same profile)?

Comment: Thanks for  interest, I have updated the answer with required information :-)

Comment: I guess, you need to do the authentication each time you load your file.

Answer (score 2):

On Google Chrome, I was seeing this issue randomly and it mentioned not being able to load the file `/some/google/path/thats/gone/because/this/fixed/it/client.js`. I tried clearing my cache and hard reloading, and sure enough, Colab starting working again.

Comment: I had a similar experience. But in my case, I discovered that it was the ad-blocker that was causing it. I removed it and Colab started working  again.

Answer (score 1):

As with standard cookies, third-party cookies are placed so that a site can remember something about you at a later time. Both are typically used to store surfing and personalization preferences and tracking information.

Google's colaboratory uses third party cookies and your browser most likely has them disabled.

Navigate to your browser settings, search for cookies and enable third party cookies. This should hopefully fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I just disabled AdBlock on google Colab in everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try to close/pause AdBlock and reload the page, it works for me.

Comment: Your answer is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155953).